# Sitecore CD Pages with anonymous rights are redirecting to login page

Tags: identity-server, federated-authentication, adfs

We have integrated OnPrem ADFS for authentication with OnPrem Sitecore setup. ADFS is used to authenticate both sitecore CM and CD.
We have allowed some of the pages for anonymous user(from Security Access Viewer) so those could be accessed with out login from CD.
Recently On one of the environments we are facing an issue on sitecore CD where user is redirecting to login page when accessing the anonymous pages.
We could not find the root cause and there are no recent changes that could cause this issue.

Anyone faced a similar issue or could provide any help to find the root cause would be great help.

Sitecore version 9.3

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar setup as you decribe, whereby ADFS was used to control access to the CD environment.

Assuming you followed the same approach, by creating a new domain and adding that to the sites node.

If so, there are some setting there that could cause the issue you are describing. Please review your config (`App_Config/Security/Domains.config`) and specifically these settings:

**anonymousUserName**: The name of the anonymous user for the domain (without the domain name). Set to blank to disable the anonymous user for the domain. Optional - default value: Anonymous

**ensureAnonymousUser**: Indicates if the domain should ensure that an anonymous user for the domain exists in the Membership database. Optional - default value: false

**everyoneRoleName**: The name of the everyone role for the domain (without the domain name). Set to blank to disable the everyone role for the domain. Optional - default value: Everyone

Im guessing you may have set anonymousUserName and everyoneRoleName to blank?

Some further info here: https://deanobrien.uk/sitecore-identity-server-mapping-custom-fields-and-roles-from-azure-ad/

Comment: Thanks Dean for the explanation. But we do not have any entry for the 3 settings, hence they should be the default values.
Let me know, if you can provide any more information or suggestions

Comment: Can you confirm that annonymous user has access to the same pages on other environments? Is domains.config same on all?

Comment: Yes, domains.config is same across the environments

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dean's answer, you can also try checking permissions for the page that should be available to anonymous users.

To do this, go to the **Launchpad → Access Viewer**, then select your anonymous user for the website (by default it is extranet\Anonymous but can also be a custom domain if you configured it). After this, find your page in the tree and select the **Read** permission.

On the right hand site there will be a block explaining why the specified account can or can't read this page:

[image: Access Viewer]

If the anonymous user does not have read access to the page, then Sitecore will redirect anonymous users to the login page automatically (assuming that you have the `loginPage` specified in the `<site>` config).

Depending on how permissions were set for the pages, it is possible that some security rules have changed on the page itself or its parent items so it's worth double checking that the security permissions are still correct.

If permissions are correct, you can also check if there are any custom processors in the `<httpRequestBegin>` pipeline that can override the standard item resolving logic and trigger a redirect to the login page.

Comment: Thanks Anna for the detailed explanation. I have tried providing access to extranet\Anonymous and customDomain\Anonymous  and still getting redirected to Login page. I have verified that there are no such pipeline, which could cause such a behavior.

Comment: Thanks @DeepakJena, please make sure that your publish items after updating security permissions on them. If it still does not work as expected, please show us a screenshot of Access Viewer for your anonymous user

Comment: Thanks Anna, I have published the items post security update and verified on Web DB as well. 
Here is a screenshot of the Access Viewer
https://snipboard.io/MQXih8.jpg

Comment: And Everyone Role has access to Sitecore root node

Comment: @DeepakJena ah, looks like this screenshot is from the Security Editor. Please could you make a similar screenshot but in the Access Viewer? Access Viewer will show the final result after combining all the permissions from this item and its parent items. Potentially there is a "deny" rule somewhere and it overrides all "allow" rules.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Here is the screenshot . https://snipboard.io/E0sRMf.jpg

Comment: Hmm, this looks like everything is correct, at least the homepage should be publicly available and not redirecting. Is it the same for child pages too? Another thing you can check is the `requireLogin` attribute in your `<site>` config. If it is set to "true", all pages of the website will redirect to login page regardless of security permissions.

Comment: "requireLogin"  is not set in any of the sites. Let me know, if you could provide any more information. 
Thanks again for checking this.

Comment: @DeepakJena thanks for checking! One last thing I can suggest is trying to load the website in an incognito window or clear cookies. Similar behaviour can happen if CM and CD roles are combined in one Sitecore instance and you loaded Experience Editor/Preview. Sitecore will remember that you last browsed the website in Experience Editor mode by save it in the cookie `sitename#sc_mode`. If your session expires and you try to open a front-end URL on the same domain, Sitecore will redirect you to the login page so that you can access Experience Editor.